# JEST unit testing for $.get request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have a code in React

```
$.get('/bin/data', (response) => {
            this.data = response;
        });
```

This is my test case:

```
$document = {
            on: jest.fn().mockName('$document.on'),
        };

        expect(window.$).toBeUndefined(); 
        $ = jest.fn().mockName('$').mockReturnValue($document);
        $.get = () => {};
        jest.spyOn($, 'get').mockName('$.get').mockImplementation(response => jest.fn()); // not sure what to do here such that callback function is also covered

        window.$ = $;
```

Everything is working fine, but the callback function is not getting covered.

Answer (score 0):

Got if solved.

```
jest.spyOn($, 'get').mockName('$.get').mockImplementation((url, myMockFn) => {
            myMockFn({ name: 'Tom' });
        });
```